# php preg_replace regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am having some problem with my regular expression in preg_replace function. My code is as below.

```
$html = preg_replace("/{.*:C/", "func_call(", 'Hi Kevin. Your address is {Address:S111}. Your customer name is {Customer:C111}. Your customer id is {CustomerId:C1112}. You use laptop brand {Laptops:I4}. Thanks.');

print_r($html);
```

I am trying to replace `{Customer:C111}` by `func_call(1111}` and `{CustomerId:C1112}` by `func_call(1112}`. So I am expecting to get

> Hi Kevin. Your address is {Address:S111}. Your customer name is
>   func_call(1111}. Your customer id is `func_call(1112`}. You use laptop
>   brand {Laptops:I4}. Thanks.

As you can see everything in the format {anything:Cnumber} will need to be replaced by func_call(number}

Currently am getting

> Hi Kevin. Your address is func_call(1112}. You use laptop brand
>   {Laptops:I4}. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php > $str = 'Hi Kevin. Your address is {Address:S111}. Your customer name is {Customer:C111}. Your customer id is {CustomerId:C1112}. You use laptop brand {Laptops:I4}. Thanks.';
php > echo preg_replace('#\{\w+:C(\d+)\}#', 'func_call(\\1)', $str);
Hi Kevin. Your address is {Address:S111}. Your customer name is func_call(111). Your customer id is func_call(1112). You use laptop brand {Laptops:I4}. Thanks.
```

Comment: Oh, wait, I misread - you need `func_call(123*}*`, not `func_call(123*)*` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/{\w+:C/
```

As your regex. `.*` is greedy, it will consume as much as it can.

This a very weird looking thing to do BTW.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the non-greedy version of `*`.

Try this:

```
$html = preg_replace("/{.*?:C/", "func_call(", 'Hi Kevin. Your address is {Address:S111}. Your customer name is {Customer:C111}. Your customer id is {CustomerId:C1112}. You use laptop brand {Laptops:I4}. Thanks.');
```

Comment: I thought about this, but it will still fail, won't it? Wont the `.*?` consume `Address:S111}. Your customer name is {Customer`? It's not greedy so it won't consume to the very last `:C` but it will still start after the first `{`, no? Or does non-greedy search for the shortest match if there are multiple? I'm not sure. I thought it just meant it would stop at the first match.

Comment: It works okay because it is followed by a colon.  The regex `.*?:` will consume all characters up until the first colon.  Another way to do this is `[^:]*:`.  Does that help?

Comment: `[^:]*:` would work, yes. The other way isn't *just* followed by a colon though, it's followed by `:C`, so in a example like `{a:B} {a:C}` it would start at `a` and go to `:C`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = preg_replace("/\{([^:]+)\:([^\}]+)\}/", "func_call(\$2)", 'Hi Kevin. Your address is {Address:S111}. Your customer name is {Customer:C111}. Your customer id is {CustomerId:C1112}. You use laptop brand {Laptops:I4}. Thanks.');
```

"search for `{`, followed by anything but `:`, remember it in `$1`, then match the first `:` followed by anything but `}`, remember it in $2. replace the while match with `func_call($2)`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Was quite useful

Answer (score 0):

if you wish you can do this without preg_replace
something like this

```
$string ="Hi Kevin. Your address is %s. Your customer name is %s. Your customer id is %s. You use laptop brand %s. Thanks.'";
    $string = sprintf($string,'{Address:S111}','{Customer:C111}','{CustomerId:C1112}','{Laptops:I4}');
```